# Selenium Web driver wait for long time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Can I wait with Selenium Web Driver for a long time period?

Even though I can set implicitlywait command like below, it doesn't wait the time that I've given.

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Is there anything wrong here?

In my case, I need to execute one test case and wait for 4 minutes and then execute the next test case.

I use Java here.

Comment: That is not what the implicit wait function is for - if you have a waiting period between tests, you will need to input your own logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this is not my answer, Two days ago I saw this answer here, But I had no time to apply it.Today I tried it and that's what exact I wanted.

Unfortunately Now I can not see that answer here.So I added this answer and all credits should go to the user who posted this answer here.

In this case what I wanted to do is to wait the driver for 5 mins so that until execute the periodical cron job.

`Thread.sleep(4000);` to pause execution of program.

Comment: The other answer is far better than this answer.

Comment: It's only better if you misunderstood kushan's original question. He wanted to know how to wait between tests, which is best carried out by using thread.sleep. Arran is right; the wait functionality is not meant for this sort of thing. Aimbire's answer is more correct if the question was how to wait for an element, but it wasn't. Kushan posted the solution to the question that he actually asked, not the one people seem to think he asked. It's not fair to downvote him for that.

Comment: I had the same problem as kushan, thanks for having this reposted :)

Answer (score 9):

Considering you need to wait for a particular element i'd do something in the lines of a ExplicitWait like below.

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300); // The int here is the maximum time in seconds the element can wait.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someId")));
```

On this case you can use any of the [ExpectedConditions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) you'd like.
Also not having to use a big wait time on some very particular cases. This imho is a good practice.

Comment: Thanks aimbire; But actually what I want here is wait for nothing just just sleep the thread until some back end scripts are executed.You may get mislead with implicit wait command.

Comment: So you should use this wait for it to wait a trigger (that allows you to know in the DOM finished working the scripts)