# Session is getting closed when waiting for 5 minutes in Selenium

Tags: multithreading, selenium, session, driver, page-refresh

I'm using Thread.sleep(310),means waiting for 5 minutes in my script level.
I don't have any other option,as per my application i need to wait 5 minutes then need to refresh() ,then only i will get certain text on my page that text i need to verify.
Currently i'm using like this `Thread.sleep(310);driver.refresh();`
While waiting for 5 minutes my selenium script is getting closed and getting error as session lost.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @jsheeran,Yes Please.My session is getting closed in selenium script.

Comment: The units for [`Thread.sleep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) are milliseconds... not seconds. Not to mention 300s is 5 mins not 310. Please post the code you are using and any error message, etc. that you are getting. Also post the HTML before and after the desired text appears. You should be able to use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the text to appear instead of using `Thread.sleep()`. `Thread.sleep()` is almost always a bad practice.

Comment: @JeffC, we are using as Thread.sleep(300 * 1000L); means 5 minutes ,after waiting of 5 minutes i need to refresh the page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893781/selenium-web-driver-wait-for-long-time

Comment: If you aren't using the code in your question, then please update the question with the code you are actually using. Why do you need to wait 5 minutes? Is it always exactly 5 minutes or ? You still haven't posted the HTML that I requested yesterday.

Comment: @JeffC,Every time i need to wait exactly 5 minutes and after need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebdriverWait with custom ExpectedConditions. For example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Title")); // if your title same
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(%your_web_element%)); // if you have element that shouldn't change during this time
```